# Why does file_get_contents function give me a syntax error when used in PHPUnit test, but works fine otherwise?

Tags: php, phpunit

I have a class that I'm trying to run tests on. One of the functions is supposed to take in a fairly long string as one of its parameters. In production, this string will come from the database, but for now, I'm just reading out of a .txt file.

In the early stages, I was just testing by adding this to the bottom of the same file the class is in:

```
$testFile = file_get_contents('./test.txt');
```

and then passing `$testFile` into the function, and that worked fine. But now I'm trying to make some actual unit tests, and here's what I have to test that, and bare in mind, my experience with PHPUnit is pretty limited:

```
class StackTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public $file = file_get_contents('/path/to/test.txt');

    public function setUp() {
        //instantiate object using $file
    }

    public function testFileParser() {
        //test the function
    }
}
```

But when I run PHPUnit on this test, it give me this error:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' in /path/to/tests/tests.php on line 9
```

With line 9 being the line that `file_get_contents` is on. Anyone know why it's doing this?

Comment: You cannot initialize a member variable with functions. Initialize the variable as empty string and use the `__construct()` method to write the file contents to the variable on class initialization.

Comment: Move `$file = file_get_contents('/path/to/test.txt');` to function setUp().
You can't init a variable of class by calling other function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use functions to initialize a property.

You may do it in a method like in your case :

```
class StackTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

public $file;

public function setUp() {
     $this->file = file_get_contents('/path/to/test.txt');
}

public function testFileParser() {
    //test the function
}
```

}